# DES Decryption issue for objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, des

I have to decrypt a data in Objective C. The decryption scheme is DES/ECB/NoPadding  with following input data = 741DCDDF1C216EEF and key = D9C44F6D2589255E and output should be 34160D6EADAD6D86 with the following code am getting output as aec6f702 5b4619e1 064db829 925a10d7

i am passing input as

```
uint8_t ksn10[16] = { 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0C, 0x04, 0x04, 0x0F, 0x06, 0x0D,
    0x02, 0x05, 0x08, 0x09, 0x02, 0x05, 0x05, 0x0E};
uint8_t bytes32[16] = { 0x07, 0x04, 0x01, 0x0D, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0F,
    0x01, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x0E, 0x0E, 0x0F};

NSData *TMKKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:ksn10 length:16];
NSData *SessionKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes32 length:16];
```

method definition:

```
NSData *encoded_data=  [self DESCrypto:(NSData*)TMKKey:(NSData*)SessionKey:kCCDecrypt:     [SessionKey length]:kCCAlgorithmDES:kCCKeySizeDES:kCCOptionECBMode|0x0000];

NSLog(@"%@", encoded_data);
```

method call :

```
-(NSData*)DESCrypto :(NSData *)key :(NSData*)dataIn :(CCOperation)CryptOperation :(int)inlength :(CCAlgorithm)type :(size_t)keysize :(CCOptions)mode
```

{

```
char dataOut[16000];
bzero(dataOut, sizeof(dataOut));
size_t numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted=0;
char iv[8]={0};
CCCryptorStatus result =CCCrypt(CryptOperation,type,mode,[key bytes],keysize,iv,[dataIn bytes],inlength, dataOut, sizeof(dataOut), &numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted);

NSLog(@"CryptoStatus:%d",result);



NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:dataOut length:numBytesEncryptedorDecrypted];

return data;
```

}

but am not getting  correct output. please help me to get 34160D6EADAD6D86 as output and let me know what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Your code is using 0D090C04040F060D020507090205050E and not D9C44F6D2589255E.  I'm guessing that is one of the problems?

Comment: ur guess is right thank you..now i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the data and key to the correct hex representation and the decryption does produce the correct value:

```
input data: 741DCDDF1C216EEF
key:        D9C44F6D2589255E
output:     34160D6EADAD6D86
```

Test (no error checking, all inputs assumed correct):

```
uint8_t dataInBytes[8] = { 0x74, 0x1D, 0xCD, 0xDF, 0x1C, 0x21, 0x6E, 0xEF };
int dataLength = 8;
uint8_t keyBytes[8] = { 0xD9, 0xC4, 0x4F, 0x6D, 0x25, 0x89, 0x25, 0x5E };
uint8_t *dataOutBytes = calloc(1, dataLength);

CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
        kCCAlgorithmDES, kCCOptionECBMode,
        keyBytes, kCCKeySizeDES,
        NULL,
        dataInBytes,  dataLength,
        dataOutBytes, dataLength,
        NULL);

NSString *s = @"dataOutBytes: ";
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {s = [s stringByAppendingFormat:@"%02X", dataOutBytes[i]];}
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

output:

```
dataOutBytes: 34160D6EADAD6D86
```

Comment: Not able to find the solution for more than 2 days..but u done that .Thank you so much for your timely help